# Is it possible to customize FCM push notification which I receive while app backgrounded?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

If the application is in the foreground I am able to customize the notification though I read when app is backgrounded. The FCM handles the notifications by default(Does that mean we can not customize those notifications?)

Comment: It's possible. Just use a `data`-*only* message payload.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase/38795553#38795553

Comment: What you want to costumize exactly?

Answer (score 0):

By default you will receive:

```
"notification":{
     "title": "Awesome notif!",
     "body": "Test notif"
 }
```

This one will be handle only when you're in foreground.

if you send:

```
"data":{
     "title": "Awesome notif!",
     "body": "Test notif"
 },
```

it will be handle by both background and foreground.

I highly recommend you to read [this article](https://medium.com/@Miqubel/mastering-firebase-notifications-36a3ffe57c41#.vr54tf7wp) it explains everything you have to know about that.